# Is there a fast way to rebase a long history of commits to master branch?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I've been working for the past two weeks on a feature, and I created a separate branch for it. The problem is that the task took me a long time, and I didn't rebase my branch to master periodically. I ended up with 100+ commits and now when I'm trying to rebase the branch to master using `git rebase master`, it is taking forever, as I need to check the conflict for each each commit, modify it, `git add` and then `git rebase --continue`.

Is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: Not really, no...not unless you're not opposed to a straight-up merge to do it all in one go.

Comment: I don't want to merge and I want to use rebase so i can rewrite commits history. Aw is there any workaround even if that mean to lose my commits history for that branch? I just want to make sure the latest code for that branch rebased to master?

Comment: Then you'll have to deal with each merge conflict as you rebase.  You'd really rather *not* lose the work you've done.

Comment: this will take forever :(

Comment: why do a rebase? whats wrong with a merge as you still have the history. and even better you can unmerge it if it's bad

Comment: @dalore one time I did that and then a few months later a team member called my code "garbage". I tried blamed the code and saw that I wasn't the author. The merge messed up the commit history and made me the author! That's why I rebase...

Comment: But it doesn't make you the author and doesn't mess up the history. If anything it preserves the history and one can create the same rebased log view from the log without having to rebase.

Comment: Surprised there is no mention of git rerere which should reduce the pain of resolving repetitive conflicts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500943/what-is-git-rerere-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This depends in part how you've done your 100+ commits and what's been happening in the meantime. Four strategies might be useful:

## Reduce the number of commits to rebase

If you have a beautiful clear stream of 100 commits that never modify the same code twice, I'm sorry, but you are stuck.

However, from 100 commits in two weeks, I'm guessing your commit history does not look like that. Perhaps you've modified function X 5 times within the commit history, and each one of those commits is going to cause a conflict. If only you had one single commit that modified function X, you'd have 20% of the work to do.

So the answer here is to tidy up your commit history before you rebase onto master. This is another use for 'git rebase'. Rebase it onto its *existing* base, but use `git rebase -i` to interactively squash together and reorder the commits. Make sure you have the minimum number of commits and that each of those does something independent. You can take the opportunity to change your commit logs too. Key backup branches (`git branch`) and `git diff` to those after each commit to check you've not changed anything.

In particular, if you have internal merge commits, flattening these is helpful.

Inevitably when I do this I find stuff I did wrong, or could have done better, even if it's 'only' code formatting or commit messages. You can take the opportunity to fix these. I'm guessing you should be down to 10 or 20 commits when this is done - far more manageable.

## Rebase in stages

If you've already done that, you are probably going to have to bite the bullet. However, if a colleague has been refactoring whilst you've been working, sometimes what you are best doing is as follows. Imagine the tree looks a bit like this:

```
    A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- F -- .... -- X --- Y --- Z (master)
     \
      \----- 1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 .... 97 --- 98 --- 99 --- 100 (you)
```

What you want to do ultimately is to rebase onto Z. However, this gives you loads of conflicts. Let's suppose commits D and E are two megacommits from a colleague refactoring something your code is dealing with. Sometimes, it's easier to:

- Rebase onto C (this shouldn't be much work)
- Take a deep breath and rebase onto E
- Rebase onto master (this shouldn't be much work)

## Avoiding complexity on the 'master' side

Sometimes things have got really complicated on the tree you are trying to merge into. A classic case is that (using the above diagram), commit G reverts commit C, then commit H redoes (or almost redoes) it, and in the mean time there are merges (particularly of things you've might have merged in too). Thanks colleague, that's made rebasing really simple. Other things that cause difficulties are complex merge commits and nasty renames. Each commit tends to give you the same conflicts again and again for no apparent reason. `git rebase` Aarrggh.

One technique here is to flatten a copy of the master tree, i.e. branch master (locally), then rebase it squashing the whole thing into a single commit from A to Z. You can flatten your stuff a little first too (see above). Then rebase onto the flattened master. Now you've got the 'right' set of commits, you can easily rebase that onto master (well, onto 'Z' as master may change) because the code's exactly the same.

## If all else fails

Sometimes `git rebase` seems to go into a fugue state of conflicts, and it's time to break out `git format-patch` and `git am` to reapply it in whole or in bits. This is really useful if someone has renamed a file (as you can fix the filename in the patch in your editor) or renamed a common class/variable/whatever (as you can find/replace in the patch).

## Learn from your mistakes

Next time, rebase onto master more frequently. It's less painful if you do it as you go along.

Also, if you have two people working on the same area of code and it produces a pile of conflicts, perhaps your code's not well abstracted enough, or perhaps you are working on top of each other and could divide up your work better?

Answer (score 19):

### rebase via merge

Let me describe approach I have found.

I had the same rebase pain, without "just merge" option. And I knew that we have rebase flag **-X theirs**, which automatically resolves all conflicts with our changes, but that works mechanically and we are losing external changes.

But what if we could add one additional commit to restore project state from a temporary merge? And I found and easy way to do that.

First, checkout temp branch and start merge

```
git checkout -b temp
git merge origin/master
```

You will have to resolve conflicts, but only once and only real ones.
Then stage all files and finish merge.

```
git commit -m "Merge branch 'origin/master' into 'temp'"
```

Then return to your branch (let it be **alpha**) and start rebase automatically resolving any conflicts.

```
git checkout alpha
git rebase origin/master -X theirs
```

Branch has been rebased, but project is probably in invalid state. That's OK, we have one final step. We just need to restore project state, so it should be like we have on branch 'temp'. Technically we just need to copy it's **tree** (folder state) via low-level command **git commit-tree**. Plus merging into current branch just created commit.

```
git merge --ff $(git commit-tree temp^{tree} -m "Fix after rebase" -p HEAD)
```

And delete temporary branch

```
git branch -D temp
```

That's all. We did a hard rebase via hidden merge.

Also I developed a script, so it can be done in dialog manner, you can find it [here](https://github.com/capslocky/git-rebase-via-merge).

Comment: Seeing the below error while running the above git merge -ff command:
"Unknown switch -p"

Comment: @sekhar are you executing that whole line in bash? Because "-p" is a well-known option for git-commit-tree, see the docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree

Answer (score 2):

I just create a new branch from master, then squash and merge your feature branch on to that new branch. Now you have a branch with all your code in a single commit.

Answer (score 0):

I saw lot of post and example of this, but none suits when you have 100+ commits prob most of them you have to resolve conflicts. I had earlier merged/rebased so my branch was basically a mess. So it seemed hard to do simple squash/rebase.

This is what i did ultimately. Reduced my conflict resolution from probably 30+ times to just 2 :).
I think you can also hard reset your branch to master instead of step 2 below (`git rebase -i`) and have same effect (with only 1 conflict resolution)

```
git reset --hard master
```

1. Make a backup of your project folder.
2. 

```
git rebase -i mainbranch #it will open a editor.
```

3. Drop all commit Leave fist pick: replace rest of the  'pick' with 'd'

```
pick abas121 first commit
d abas122 sec commit
d abas123 third commit
d abas124 fourth commit
```

4. Resolve if any conflict (only once), and Commit (only commit, no push/pull).
5. Copy back your changes from the backup project folder (all except .git, or just the changes if they are small).
6. Do git difference and resolve conflicting changes. Adjust your changes to the latest from master.
7. Commit. Look at commit history and make sure its good.
8. Force push to your remote branch.

```
git push --force.
```

Comment: so I have a question, why just pick up the first commit?